# $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ increasing and convex $\Rightarrow f(x_0)\le f(x)-c(x-x_0)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f',f''\ge0$ on the whole real line.

Then for every $x_0$ fixed, $\exists\; c\in\Bbb R$ s.t. 
$$
f(x_0)\le f(x)-c(x-x_0)\;\;,\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb R.
$$

Now $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is the angular coefficient of the line passing thru $(x,f(x))$ and $(x_0,f(x_0))$, so being $f$ increasing, we have that
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\ge f'(x_0)=:c
$$
which leads to the wanted relation for $x> x_0$ **ONLY**. How can I prove that the wanted relation holds for **EVERY** $x\in\Bbb R$?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the reflection of $f(x)$ about $x_0$: i.e., $f(-x+2x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

I got it: for $x<x_0$ we have that (and this will hold because of the $f',f''\ge0$)
$$
\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}=
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\le f'(x_0)=:c
$$
from which, multiplying both sides by $x-x_0$ (which now is negative) we get
$$
f(x)-f(x_0)\ge c(x-x_0)
$$
which holds to the wanted relation.

Observe that in the first part of my post I wrote that being $f$ increasing, for $x>x_0$ we have
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\ge f'(x_0)=:c
$$
but this is true even because $f''\ge0$ (if convexity changes, the above relation doesn't hold in general, draw a picture).